# Automate Mouse and Keyboard interactions similiar to OneClick for MacOS 9?

Tags: software-recommendation, automator

I need to batch a process that requires me to automate some key presses.  All I need to be able to do is hit the enter key, wait 5 seconds, hit the enter key again, wait 5 minutes, and then cmd + w to close the current window.

In the MacOS 9 days I would use OneClick by WestCode software:
http://www.macworld.com/article/15791/2000/12/13reviews2oneclick.html

Is there a similar tool for MacOS X, Snow Leopard specifically?  In this particular instance I do not need to can the focus of windows or anything else.  I just need to automate key presses within a program at various intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I could find was to use a combination of Automator's "Watch Me Do" actions and AppleScript to simulate key presses.  I wrote a tutorial and posted my Automator workflow here:

http://www.johnkramlich.com/blog/2011/05/24/batch-exporting-adobe-flash-flas-to-quicktime-movies/

More info about AppleScript "System Events" for simulating key presses here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AppleScript_Programming/System_Events

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use automator and its record actions feature? Described [here](http://automator.us/leopard/features/virtual-user.html)

Comment: The "Watch Me Do" action in Automator doesn't record everything, unfortunately.